# Parse a CSV File that is stored in a ZipEntry/ZipInputStream variable using apache commons CSV(CSVRecord,CSVFormat,etc)

Tags: java

I have been succesfully been able to write code for TWO different things:

1.- printing, in the console, the content of a CSV file that comes as an attachment(from a web service) by converting it to a ZipInputStream/ZipEntry (it comes inside a zip file)

2.- parse the content of a CSV file that is on my disk using CSVFormat/CSVRecord/etc, here is the code for this one (number 2):

```
public static void printCSVFile() throws IOException {
    Reader in = new FileReader("file123.csv");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in);
    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        String columnOne = record.get(0);
        String columnTwo = record.get(1);

    }
}
```

Now, what I want to do, is the same that I do in number 2, except that instead of a CSV file located on my disk, I want to use that csv file from step one(the one that is not on disk, but the one that is on a zipentry)

Another, shorter way to ask my question is: is there a way to convert a ZipEntry variable that contains a CSVp file into a Reader variable so that I can pass it as a parameter to the parse method from the code I showed?:

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(Reader variable);
```

EDIT**: In case you don't know the answer to the first question, maybe a simpler question is. What if I had the string containing the line that I want to parse?
Is there a way to convert from String to Reader? like:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("line string that I want to parse");
```

Comment: For the EDIT** thing: replace `FileReader` by `StringReader` and you are done …

Comment: And to convert an `InputStream` to a `Reader`: ever heard about `InputStreamReader`?